# How to create a DLL callable from batch using rundll32.exe

Tags: winapi, dll

With rundll32 it is possible to call simple APIs into DLLs.

Two questions:

- for this usage, should be the entry point use the `__cdecl` calling convention, or some other calling convention?
- is it possible to pass only numeric args or also strings?

Comment: But see [What's the guidance on when to use rundll32?  Easy: Don't use it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use *rundll32.exe*. I can't word it any better than Raymond Chen did: [What’s the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don’t use it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643).

If you read through the blog entry, and are still convinced, that this is the solution you need, here is the [deal](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787): The entry point must follow the `__stdcall` calling convention:

```
void CALLBACK
EntryPointW(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPWSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

The trailing `W` is important, so that the *lpszCmdLine* argument is passed as Unicode (UTF-16LE). *EntryPoint* is a placeholder, it can be any legal symbol.

As an example, you can export a symbol called `MyFunctionW`, and pass an arbitrary command line using:

```
rundll32.exe MyDll.dll,MyFunction 132 C:\WINDOWS\INF\SHELL.INF
```

But really, you should evaluate other options (e.g. [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714469.aspx)). Convenience doesn't come for free.

Answer (score 2):

The entry point must use the `__stdcall` calling convention:

```
  void CALLBACK
  EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

This is covered in the following documentation:

[NFO: Windows Rundll and Rundll32 Interface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787)