# RunDLL32 does not execute anything

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to create a DLL which can be executed with RunDLL32. I know that RunDLL32 is running correctly because if I execute the following command, it pops up a message box:
`rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry`/.
However I cannot get it to execute a DLL that I created, which looks like this:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(0, L"Hello1", 0, 0);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(0, L"Hello2", 0, 0);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        MessageBox(0, L"Hello3", 0, 0);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        MessageBox(0, L"Hello4", 0, 0);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The code compiles fine (In Visual Studio 2017, Release mode, x64) but when I execute

`RunDLL32 MyDLL.dll`

Nothing happens. There are no error messages, not output, and no message boxes. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Since your are compiling a 64bit DLL, make sure you are running the 64bit version of RunDll32:

[rundll32.exe equivalent for 64-bit DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703635/)

Per [this page](https://ss64.com/nt/rundll32.html):

> If you pass the wrong type of DLL to Rundll32, it may fail to run without returning any error message.

Even if you could get RunDLL32 to load your DLL, [you can't safely call `MessageBox()` in `DllMain()` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377569/).

You need to [export a function for RunDLL32 to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986227/) besides your `DllMain`. You can call `MessageBox()` in that function, eg:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CALLBACK MyFunctionW(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPWSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBoxW(hwnd, lpszCmdLine, L"Hello", MB_OK);
}
```

```
rundll32 my.dll,MyFunction "hello world"
```